# framework missmatch after mono-update on visual-studio for mac

Tags: .net, xamarin

After VS for MAC updates I cannot build certain projects anymore.

**Error**:

> The primary reference "Splat" could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETPortable,Version=v5.0" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7".

I don't wont to change the code, because a lot of people are working on this project. I already tried all kind of Mono-versions and a fresh install of VS for mac but nothing helps.

Edit:
I updated VS completely and downgraded splat in ever project that was complaining from 2.0 to 1.6       ....\packages\Splat.2.0.0\lib\netstandard1.1\Splat.dll
....\packages\Splat.1.6.0\lib\Portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80\Splat.dll

I had to re-enable some projekt to the debug-build again as my solution was also complaning that some parts were not built... don't know why this happens but I also needed this step.

Then I ran again... 
I'm using Rider now and don't have to use the above downgrade nor the re-enable of some projects. Rider just does the job, somehow...

Comment: ,can you try to uninstall Splat and install again in your project again?

Comment: thanks for our input, but this tip resolves in the same error-message

Comment: now you solved your issue?

Comment: See my edit in the original Post